# How to identify multiple lines/clusters in a single dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, linear-regression, multiclass-classification

I'm currently struggling to wrap my head around how multi-linear regression could be done to find separate sets of linear models in a single data set. I can perform regression on single data set for a single regressor and coef with no problem, but what if there are a known-number of lines existing in a single data space?

My first approach was to use hierarchical clustering to identify the points using ML first, but it doesn't seem to capture individual cluster variance in Euclidean space as expected. My second trial was KMeans, which still relies on Euclidean distance so it creates clusters with radii. My last thought process led to Kmedian, but at this point I was wondering what other people might think regarding this problem. If this is the right direction, I know I would have to project points in a better space(i.e. an axis that captures more-or most- variance) before I apply these methods.

I would appreciate any comments or input in any shape or form.

Thank you,

3-line summary: Linear regression on dataset with multiple lines Clustering first, then multiple single linear regression? or have you guys come across a module for this such thing?

I would truly appreciate any insights;

Comment: An picture of what you want to do would be nice. A useful keyword might be "mixture models"

Comment: Thank you @Valentas,